# dispose function not called in my flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, lifecycle

i am trying to call **request**  when user close the application
i tried to call the request inside on **dispose** function but not working
and i tried to use WidgetsBindingObserver but i didn't find any case when user close the app

```
  @mustCallSuper
  @protected
  @override
  void dispose() {


    print('-----dispose--------');
    homeController.setUserOnlineStatus(status: false); //this is my request  
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
    homeController.setUserOnlineStatus(status: false); //this is my request   again 

  }
```

this is my code
any one has solution to this issue

Comment: In what kind of Widget is this  void dispose()??

Comment: This most likely means your widget is not being removed from the widget tree. Maybe try disposing the homeController after setUserOnlineStatus but before super.dispose();

Answer (score -1):

Here how to handle App Life Cycle:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() => {WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this), super.initState()};

  @override
  void dispose() => {WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this), super.dispose()};

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      // The application is visible and responding to user input.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      //The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      //The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding to user input, and running in the background.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      // The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is detached from any host views
        break;
    }
   
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Ciaoo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Test for App life cycle:',
            ),
            Text(
              "Ciaone",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: i added the same code 
but not of this cases work when user exit app and remove it from ram

Comment: @HassanHallak rating with -1 score an answer that shows to you and future users how to manage app life cycle is not the max for a good developer. However you are missing the point I think. There doesn't exist something to manage the `.dipsose()` method calling as it is called by framework when the Widget is removed by widget tree and this happens always, even your app is running and HAVE NOTHING TO DO WITH APP CLOSURE.